# Azure Service Fabric Scale up and out

Tags: azure, scale, azure-service-fabric

I'm new with Azure Service Fabric. I have created the smallest possible (3xA0) cluster for testing my stateless application. Ideally I wanted to use F1 instances but they were not available for some reason in Cluster Creation dialog wizard.

Now I'm trying to understand how can I manage instance count and size for my existing cluster but I can't see any menu options in Resource Manager related to this.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to convert my comment to an answer. So there are a lot of help documents covering this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-introduction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-fabric-settings

Comment: Thank you. The answer is "Service Fabric scaling is not available in administration portal yet" but it is available using powershell